# Drupal - need to change box content

Tags: css, drupal, content-management-system

I am trying to do some updates on a friends site. I am very new to Drupal, and have found that it's not too hard to do most of these updates, however, one thing has me stumped

on the front page of her site:
http://lisaleslie9.com

You will see a pink box in the middle left that is about her leadership academy

however when I click to edit that box i get:

```
<div class="clear ads"><a class="ad" href="https://lisaleslie9.com/lisa-leslie-basketball-leadership-academy" id="ad-preregister" title="The Lisa Leslie Basketball &amp; Leadership Academy">The Lisa Leslie Basketball &amp; Leadership Academy....</a><span class="spacer">
```

But I need to change the sentence underneath of there where it says "One month of......."

How do I get to that??

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple you have to edit in block, Go to Site Buildings --> Blocks --> choose your block and click Configure. you can edit now to make changes and then click save. that's it.

Comment: +1. But this site appears to be a Drupal 7 one. Go to Administer > Structure > Blocks.

Comment: That code is what I get when I try to edit the block and it seems to be pulling from a CSS, but through the admin I dont have access to it, so would I need to edit through FTP?